# Using an HTML Textbox in place of an ASP.NET TextBox

Tags: asp.net, request

If I add this to the ASPX page:

```
<input id="Text1" type="text" value="Text1Value" />
```

I would expect to see "Text1" in the list of Request Form keys even WITHOUT setting the `runat=Server` property.

```
? request.Form.AllKeys
```

I realize that if I do set that propery, then I will have a server-sided HTML control that I can reference using the name `"Text1"`, but shouldn't I be able to access the text in the text box using the following  VB.NET syntax?

```
request.Form("Text1")
```

Comment: Are you sure this is inside the same form you're submitting? What does your submit button look like? You're not using "ASP.NET AJAX" are you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you need to add the name attribute. Try this

`<input id="Text1" name="Text1" type="text" value="Text1Value" />`

Comment: It's more than that. See my answer, too.

Answer (score 0):

The textbox on page1.aspx is available in teh Request.Forms collection on Page2 when posting from 2 to 1.

But, when using a ASP.NET button to postback to Page1, it seems not to be. Dunno why yet...